# Hide nested field from result

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework. I have a serializer with nested data and I want to hide a specific field (password):

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    # django's auth model 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source="user.username")
    password = serializers.CharField(source="user.password")

    # Other fields related to MyUser model

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ( ..., "password")
        write_only_fields = ("password",)
```

The first problem is that if I remove password from `fields` it will error saying that I have `password` defined but it's not found in the `fields` list.

`write_only_fields` does not having any effect on `password`; it's always returned.

Is there a way to keep the password for write only and remove it from the result?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing `write_only_fields` and modified the field itself to write_only:

`password = serializer.CharField(source="user.password", write_only=True)`.

I have no idea why `write_only_fields` and `extra_kwargs` did not work.

Comment: yup! This worked for me too. `write_only_fields` and `extra_kwargs` doesn't work on nested serializer fields, you need to declare them in the nested class.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because the `write_only_fields` attribute of `Meta` class only overrides the implicit fields (the ones that are only listed in the `Meta` class `fields` attributes, and not defined in the `ModelSerializer` scope) `write_only` attribute to be `True`. If you declare a `ModelSerializer` field explicitly you must define all the attributes that are not default for it to work.

The right code should be something like:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    # django's auth model 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source="user.username")
    password = serializers.CharField(source="user.password", write_only=True)

    # Other fields related to MyUser model

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ( ..., "password")
        write_only_fields = ("password",)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the function that builds the nested fields.  Good choice for when you want to display the default auth_user's name in a nested ListView.

```
from rest_framework.utils.field_mapping import get_nested_relation_kwargs

def build_nested_field(self, field_name, relation_info, nested_depth):
    """
    Create nested fields for forward and reverse relationships.
    """
    class NestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = relation_info.related_model
            depth = nested_depth - 1
            fields = ['username'] # Originally set to '__all__'

    field_class = NestedSerializer
    field_kwargs = get_nested_relation_kwargs(relation_info)

    return field_class, field_kwargs
```